# Laravel does not show laravel's 404 page on every route besides /

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

On every page besides `/` I get a 404 page, and not laravel's 404 page?

[image: 404]

I have enabled `mod_rewrite`.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and my `/etc/apache2/siotes-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    </directory>
</VirtualHost
```

If I go to `joshharington.com/index.php/about` it works, but if I just go to `joshharington.com/about` it doesnt so I have gathered that it is a .htaccess problem.

I don't know much about .htaccess, but this works on my localhost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is [`mod_rewrite` enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/q/869092/1903366)?

Comment: As stated in the post, under the first picture, `I have enabled mod_rewrite`

Comment: Oh. Sorry missed that one...

Comment: Have you renamed Laravels `public` directory to `html`? If not I think your DocumentRoot should be `/var/www/html/public`

Comment: @lukasgeiter No, I am not using `public`, the files are set so that `html` is the `public` folder. From this tutorial http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/

Comment: Okay I see. This is slightly unrelated to the question, but why didn't you just change the DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html/public` instead of moving things and changing paths?

Comment: Because taking `public` out of the url is harder than this method. This method just works.

Comment: Well not really. If your DocumentRoot points at `public` it's not in the URL anymore. And apparently there's something not working with this method...

Comment: No, it works in localhost and on other projects just fine, but now with this specific one it does not work.